# How to create a semi-transparent image

Tags: images, gimp, png

I need to create a semi transparent PNG image. I dont have Photoshop, so how do I make it using gimp?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @DanielBack It's regardless of the OS, GIMP is pretty much the same on every OS.

Comment: I am using Windows XP SP3, 32 bit OS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Png is a format that supports transparency, so you just need to open the image in Gimp, duplicate the layer, reduce the opacity to the result you prefer (don't show the background while you do this... click on the eye image). Then drag the original background layer to the trash, and save the image as .png

Piece of cake, thanks for using gimp!

Comment: Thanks, are you a fan of Gimp ? or an affiliate ?

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](http://journalxtra.com/2009/09/how-to-make-a-semi-transparent-image-using-gimp/).

Comment: Just a plain link isn't very helpful - it doesn't tell us anything about what the procedure is or how it works. If you could edit your post to give us some more details, but keep the link for reference, then that would be a great improvement to this answer!

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new at this. =)